# rgb(34, 34, 34) to UIColor

Tags: ios, regex, uicolor

I have a RGB string in the form `rgb(34, 34, 34)`. I want to parse it to a `UIColor` using iOS. I believe I need a regex for this, but I can't seem to crack it. This is what I have so far.

```
NSString *regExString = @"(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)";

NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression *regEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExString
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regEx matchesInString:backgroundColorString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, backgroundColorString.length)];
```

If anybody could send me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: Do you HAVE to get an rgb string like that or can you get the actual value?

Comment: I'm receiving this RGB string from an API I don't have control over. They are delivering it in this format unfortunately.

Comment: Check my answer :) Added something that will help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

UIColor uses a 0-1 instead of 0-255 system so you just need to convert it like so:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:34.0/255.0 green:34.0/255.0 blue:34.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

**Update**

After re-reading your question I realized your real problem isn't converting to UIColor but getting the values. I don't know much about regex but NSScanner is a simple Objective-C object that can do the same thing, albeit more verbose. Try this on for size. I'm sure there could be better ways even maybe more efficient uses of the NSScanner itself but this definitely works and will work for any int values that come through.

```
NSString *backgroundColorString = @"rgb(34, 34, 34)";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:backgroundColorString];
NSString *junk, *red, *green, *blue;
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&junk];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] intoString:&red];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&junk];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] intoString:&green];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&junk];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] intoString:&blue];

UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red.intValue/255.0 green:green.intValue/255.0 blue:blue.intValue/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding! If I figure out a solution using Regex I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Why use a regex at all?

Just use percentages of 255:

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.0) green:(green/255.0) blue:(blue/255.0) alpha:1];
```

Tada!

Comment: Yeah, but sadly I don't know the RGB values beforehand. So I need to parse them out of that string. I'm downloading that string from a server.

Answer (score 0):

I made it simple using preprocessor macro.

```
#define UIColorMake(r,g,b)[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
```

how to use:

```
UIColor MyGreenColor = UIColorMake(31.0, 164.0, 23.0);
```

I'm always leaving this code in my iOS projects.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 255.0 not 215.0 ?